# How do I sudo without having to enter my password?

Tags: sudo

I'm trying to setup sudo without no password but still I get prompted for password, I'm using ubuntu, here is the relevant line from the sudoers configuration file :

```
gandalf ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: *cough* [Allowing a user to sudo without a password](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43135/allowing-a-user-to-use-sudo-without-a-password) *cough*.  UNSECURE!  You should not do this.

Comment: You can do this, but it breaks the security model. Are you absolutely sure you want to do this?

Comment: I can understand wanting to do this on a computer, say at home in a secure situation. Security forces a "good" password, which usually means long and harder to type.  Trouble is, we have to type it in VERY regularly and it gets to be tiresome.  I am not advocating against security, but, especially in the home situation, it may well be desirable to do this.

Comment: To say this "breaks the security model" is rather extreme. `sudo` is designed to facilitate passwordless operation easily and even has ready-to-go commented configuration lines in `/etc/sudoers` to allow a whole group of users to run any command as `root` without being prompted for a password. There are some adverse security implications of doing this--any program can perform actions as root without you being notified!--but an actual *attacker*, with the ability to run programs as (non-`root`) you, can already capture your password as you enter it for `sudo` (and then run `sudo` with it).

Comment: I was wanting to do this just for my ansible ci/cd user.. so that my management scripts can run unattended as part of my CI/CD process.  I wouldn't say that's inherently insecure as it's for one user and only via ssh with a private/public key pair.

Comment: What is most secure, password or keyfile. Ok, so if your computer is setup with no root login, and the user has a keyfile and an absurdly complicated password, why should it be a problem to let this authorized user su to root without entering a password?  As others already pointed out it actually just leaves another attack vector for potential hackers.

Answer (score 57):

I believe the correct line is:

```
gandalf ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Put it in the end of the file - replace `gandalf` with the appropriate username. (To edit the file, run the command `sudo visudo`.)

Comment: Thanks, putting it at the end of the file fixed it for me

Comment: Not working for me in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You have to log out and in again @Praytic

Comment: Still nothing. Strange, because in 14.04 I had no problems with this approach.

Answer (score 16):

I use the `sudo` group and have:

```
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 10):

There is one note to mention. That line should be at end of the /etc/sudoers file.

> *Why: because some configuration lines from /etc/sudoers overwrite our line.*

gandalf ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL