# Sudo Non-Password access to /sys/power/state

Tags: bash, sudo, root, permissions

On my computer, pm-hibernate appears to be broken, however using the command `echo disk > /sys/power/state` appears to work perfectly. Now I just need regular user access to it, using sudo. How do I do this?

The command `sudo echo disk > /sys/power/state` simply returns `bash: /sys/power/state: Permission denied`.

Also, I need this in a regularly used script, how can I make it so that I don't have to type in my password for it to work???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the redirection characters "separate" execution and privileges. On this command:

```
sudo echo disk > /sys/power/state
```

What you're doing is running `echo disk` as root (pointless) and then piping that, as your normal user, into a file that's owned by root, that's why you get permission denied.

This is a very common use case, what you need to do is sudo the part that actually writes to the file instead, something like this works:

```
echo disk | sudo tee /sys/power/state
```

You can also create a shell script (a file) with:

```
  echo disk > /sys/power/state
```

Name it, for instance, script.sh, then run `chmod 755 script.sh` and run that with sudo:

```
sudo /wherever/you/put/this/script.sh
```

As for running a command without needing a password, that's been discussed before: [How do I sudo without having to enter my password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168461/how-do-i-sudo-without-having-to-enter-my-password). It can be somewhat insecure; you can control which user gets to execute which command as root without password, but in this case you'd need to allow execution of the `tee` command which could allow malicious users to overwrite *any* file as root. So use with caution and please read all the documentation and understand the security implications of doing this.

Comment: You learn something new every day, I thought sudo included the entire command. I do have a question though, why did you use '|' over '>' and what does "tee" mean???

Comment: `>` directs output to a file. `|` directs output to the standard input of another *command*. `tee` is a very simple command that takes its input and outputs it to both standard output *and* to a file. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I've never used either, so I was unfamiliar with both, and before I use any command I like to figure out exactly what it does first.