# How can I use sudo after locking my password?

Tags: password, sudo, password-recovery

I was reading about passwordless authentication with ssh. So I made a key and published it to my Ubuntu server, and it worked well.

Then decided to lock my password with `passwd -l lucas`, and I was not longer able to use sudo. I was thinking that sudo would also be without a password.

My question now is: how can I regain the ability to use sudo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sudo without having to enter my password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168461/how-do-i-sudo-without-having-to-enter-my-password)

Comment: @muru: not really a duplicate (now that I have edited the question).

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Not of that question, but now it's duplicate of the various password resetting questions. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running `passwd -l` on a user, that user can't set their password (until after it's set back to something usable).

Since you cannot use `sudo`, you'll need to reset your user account password, the same way as if you'd just forgotten what it was:

- [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)
- Or [How do I reset a lost password (using recovery mode requires me to type the password)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass)

Then you can use `sudo` again, and you can set `PasswordAuthentication no` as explained in [steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/514732/22949).

Comment: Thank you! it's setup now. I added in root mode NOPASSWD to sudo for my main user

Answer (score 2):

You will likely need to login to a root shell via the recovery console in order to re-enable your account password. After that, you can disable password login **for ssh specifically** by setting

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

in the sshd_config file, and leave the account password enabled for **local** access (including running `sudo` once you have logged in via SSH using keys)